# Flutter how to programmatically call method in custom widget?

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, custom-widgets

I'm new to Flutter and I've hit my first roadblock while trying to make a custom switch. My switch should functionally work the same like the actual `Switch` from the material library, the only difference is the UI.

I'm using `ValueNotifier` and `ValueListenableBuilder` to update the switch value from another widget. Here's the relevant parts of my code:

**Containing Widget**

```
class ParentWidget extends StatefulWidget {
    @override
    _ParentWidget createState() => _ParentWidget();
}

class _ParentWidgetState extends State<ParentWidget> {
    ValueNotifier _switchNotifier = ValueNotifier(false);

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Container(
            child: ValueListenableBuilder(
                valueListenable: _switchNotifier,
                builder: (context, switchValue, child) {
                    return _buildSwitch(switchValue);
                },
            ),
        );
    }

    Widget _buildSwitch(bool switchValue) {
        return CustomSwitch(
            key: Key(value.toString()),
            initValue: switchValue,
            onChanged: (value) {
                setState(() {
                    _switchNotifier.value = value;
                });
            },
        );
    }
}
```

**The widget that changes the switch value**

```
class ChildWidget extends StatefulWidget {
    final ValueNotifier _switchNotifier;
    ChildWidget(this._switchNotifier);

    @override
    _ChildWidgetState createState() => _ChildWidgetState();
}

class _ChildWidgetState extends State<ChildWidget> {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Container(
            child: GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                    widget._switchNotifier.value = false;
                },
                child: Image(...),
            ),
        );
    }
}
```

**Custom Switch**

```
class CustomSwitch extends StatefulWidget {
    final ValueChanged<bool> onChanged;
    final bool initValue;
    final Key key;

    const CustomSwitch({
        @required this.key,
        this.onChanged,
        this.initValue,
    });

    @override
    _CustomSwitchState createState() => _CustomSwitchState();
}

class _CustomSwitchState extends State<CustomSwitch> {
    bool value;

    @override
    void initState() {
        value = widget.initValue;
        super.initState();
    }

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        // the switch/toggle is animated just like the Material Switch
        return TheSwitch(...);
    }

    _toggle() {
        setState(() {
            value = !value;
            widget.onChanged(value);
        });
    }
}
```

If I'm calling `_toggle()` from the `CustomSwitch` the switch would toggle nicely with animation (I'm using `AnimatedPositioned` for the switch). This works fine if I'm only relying on user input, but I need to also programmatically toggle the switch and I feel like I'm missing something basic yet I'm stumped.

My current understanding is that the `CustomSwitch` would be rebuilt every time I change its value from `ChildWidget` because I'm using the switch value as a `Key`, but how to do it nicely with animation as if I'm calling `_toggle()` after it has been built?

Like in Java you'd usually do something like `customSwitch.toggle()`.

Answer (score 3):

Majority of the flutter widgets use **controllers** to interact with widgets externally (TextFormField, ListView etc).

The most simple solution for your problem would also be to create a custom controller.

Firstly you'll create a controller class, which will have your custom widget's state as a parameter. This class will also expose your widget's methods.It would Look like this:

```
class CustomWidgetController{
  _CustomWidgetState _customWidgetState;

  void _addState(_CustomWidgetState customWidgetState){
    this._customWidgetState = customWidgetState;
  }

  /// Determine if the CustomWidgetController is attached to an instance
  /// of the CustomWidget (this property must return true before any other
  /// functions can be used)
  bool get isAttached => _customWidgetState != null;

  /// Here is the method you are exposing
  void toggle() {
    assert(isAttached, "CustomWidgetController must be attached to a CustomWidget");
    _customWidgetState.toggle();
  }
}
```

You'll need to accept the Custom controller as a parameter in your CustomWidget, and pass it to its state like this:

```
class CustomSwitch extends StatefulWidget {
    final CustomWidgetController customWidgetController;
    final bool initValue;
    final Key key;

    const CustomSwitch({
        @required this.key,
        this.customWidgetController,
        this.initValue,
    });

    @override
    _CustomSwitchState createState() => _CustomSwitchState(customWidgetController, initValue);
}
```

In your custom class's state, you'll assign you class's state to the controller using the addState method we created. You can do it the constructor like this:

```
class _CustomSwitchState extends State<CustomSwitch> {
    final CustomWidgetController _customWidgetController;
    bool value;

    _CustomSwitchState(this._customWidgetController, this.value) {
    if (_customWidgetController != null)
        _customWidgetController._addState(this);
    }

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        // the switch/toggle is animated just like the Material Switch
        return TheSwitch(...);
    }

    toggle() {
        setState(() {
            value = !value;
        });
    }
}
```

Now you can pass the controller and call methods using the controller in your parent widget like this:

```
  CustomWidgetController customWidgetController = new CustomWidgetController();

  @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return CustomWidget(
            controller: customWidgetController,
            initValue: true
        );
    }
```

This is it! Now you can call `customWidgetController.toggle()` anywhere in your code to toggle the value!
This is how native widgets let you interact with them.